# How to use HttpUrlConnection and openConnection() in the below code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sqlite, androidhttpclient

I am developing login and register using the external database from a youtube tutorial that uses `HttpClient`, `HttpParams`, `HttpPost`, `HttpResponse` and `HttpEntity`. However, these functions are deprecated. Please help to modify the below code using `HttpUrlConnection`.

```
public class ServerRequests {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 15;
    public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://classpark.16mb.com/";

    public ServerRequests(Context context){
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Processing");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");

    }
    public void storeUserDataInBackground(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback){
        progressDialog.show();
        new StoreUserDataAsyncTask(user, userCallback).execute();
    }
    public void fetchUserDataInBackground(User user, GetUserCallback callback){
        progressDialog.show();
        new fetchUserDataAsyncTask(user,callback).execute();

    }
    public class StoreUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        User user;
        GetUserCallback userCallback;
        public StoreUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback){
            this.user = user;
            this.userCallback = userCallback;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... Params){
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new  ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", user.name));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", user.email));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

            HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "Register.php");

            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                client.execute(post);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            userCallback.done(null);
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }
    public class fetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,User> {
        User user;
        GetUserCallback userCallback;

        public fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback){
            this.user = user;
            this.userCallback = userCallback;
        }
        @Override
        protected User doInBackground(Void... params){
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new  ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

            HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "FetchUserData.php");

            User returnedUser = null;

            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                JSONObject j0bject = new JSONObject(result);

                if (j0bject.length() == 0){
                    returnedUser = null;
                }else {
                    String name = j0bject.getString("name");
                    String email = j0bject.getString("email");


                    returnedUser = new User(name, email,user.username, user.password);

                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return returnedUser;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(User returnedUser){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            userCallback.done(returnedUser);
            super.onPostExecute(returnedUser);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. If not, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Answer (score 0):

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html

> This class was deprecated in API level 22. Please use
>   **URLConnection** and friends instead. The Apache HTTP client is no longer maintained and may be removed in a future release.

Anyway, if you take a look at the source code, I'm sure you will find a comment which recommends a new option instead of the deprecated one. Good luck!